# Problem updating Ruby on rails view after form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have an instance variable created after the search button is pressed and an http request is performed. The result is placed in the `@albums` instance variable.

I want to show the results under the search form. Code below:

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>New Album</h1>
<h4>Search for Album</h4>

<%= form_with(url: "/albums/search", method: "get") do |f| %>
  <%= f.label(:q, "Search for: ") %>
  <%= f.text_field(:q, value: @search_query) %>
  <%= f.submit("Search") %>
<% end %>


<% if @albums %>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @albums.each do |album| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= tag.img src: album.image_url, alt: "Cover art for #{album.title}" %></td>
          <td><%= album.artist %></td>
          <td><%= album.title %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<% elsif @search_query.present? %>
  <p>No results to display :(</p>

<% end %>

<h4>Test</h4>
```

**albums_controller.rb**

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    puts "the new method was just called"
  end

  def search
    puts "inside search method"

    audio_scrobbler = AudioScrobblerSearch.new

    @search_query = params[:q]
    if @search_query
      @albums = audio_scrobbler.perform(@search_query)

      #test to make sure isnt null, will delete later
      @albums.each do |album|
        puts album.inspect
        puts
      end

      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  get "albums/search"  #search route in new.html.erb

  resources :albums

  root 'welcome#index'

end
```

My problem is after I press the search button and perform the search, the `<% if @ albums %> ...etc` segment doesnt show in the view.

Comment: Your code looks more or less correct.  I can only advise you to use `render_to_string` in that controller action in order to see the stringified output of what `render` would actually do, and if you don't see @albums in that view either, then @albums is coming back nil, or at the very least `if @albums` is being evaluated to `false` in the view and that's why it's not displaying.

Comment: Your issue is you’re calling `@albums` in your `new.html.erb` file, but you don’t have an `@albums` variable in your new action.

Comment: `form_with` by default creates form which is submitted via ajax. Check your log what type of request you get in the request line in your log. It must be js not html. You basically need to write a js template which renders result on new template. Check https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html to learn how ajax works.

Comment: Well perhaps maybe `@albums` isn't true.  Try logging the value of `@albums` to first make sure that the issue isn't with generation.